# Configuration issue when building ClamAV and OpenSSL from sources

Tags: macos, openssl, anaconda

I'm trying to build clamav-0.99.2 on OS X 10.11.6. `./configure` is getting the following error:

```
configure:17977: error: Your OpenSSL installation is misconfigured or missing

configure:17963: gcc -o conftest -I/usr/local/include  -L/usr/local/lib -lssl -lcrypto -lz conftest.c -lssl -lcrypto -lz  >&5
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_SSL_library_init", referenced from:
      _main in conftest-256c9a.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

It's just running a simple test program:

```
|    Use char because int might match the return type of a GCC
|    builtin and then its argument prototype would still apply.  */
| #ifdef __cplusplus
| extern "C"
| #endif
| char SSL_library_init ();
| int
| main ()
| {
| return SSL_library_init ();
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
```

I tried `./configure --without-ssl`, same problem.

```
checking for OpenSSL installation... /usr/local
checking for SSL_library_init in -lssl... no
configure: error: Your OpenSSL installation is misconfigured or missing
```

I've installed OpenSSL from github and it built without errors:

```
$ openssl
OpenSSL> version
OpenSSL 1.0.2l  25 May 2017
```

There may be a conflict with Anaconda's openssl:

```
$ which openssl
/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/bin/openssl
$ whereis openssl
/usr/bin/openssl
```

The function `SSL_library_init ()` isn't in the libraries:

```
$ nm /usr/local/lib/libssl.* | grep SSL_l
00000000000143a0 T _SSL_load_client_CA_file
0000000000001590 T _SSL_load_client_CA_file
00000000000143a0 T _SSL_load_client_CA_file

$ ls -l /usr/local/lib/libssl.* 
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  501464 Oct 14 14:41 /usr/local/lib/libssl.1.1.dylib
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  711256 Oct 14 14:41 /usr/local/lib/libssl.a
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel      16 Oct 14 14:41 /usr/local/lib/libssl.dylib -> libssl.1.1.dylib

$ gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

Openssl appears to have build and passes it's tests:

```
$ make test
...
All tests successful.
Files=136, Tests=1116, 643 wallclock secs ( 3.69 usr  0.55 sys + 261.00 cusr 239.88 csys = 505.12 CPU)
Result: PASS
```

Comment: *`-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel ...`* - You should be building as a regular user; and not root. The only time you need root is when you install - `sudo make install`.

Answer (score 1):

still the same problem when compiling,

Solution: install libxml2-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev

Comment: The question is asked for Mac OS, not Debian-based systems.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> $ make test
> ...
> All tests successful.
> Files=136, Tests=1116, 643 wallclock secs ( 3.69 usr  0.55 sys + 261.00 cusr 239.88 csys = 505.12 CPU)
> Result: PASS
> ```

This is the OpenSSL 1.1.0 test report. The OpenSSL 1.0.2 tests finish with:

```
$ make test
...

../util/shlib_wrap.sh ./bad_dtls_test
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/jwalton/openssl/test'
OPENSSL_CONF=apps/openssl.cnf util/opensslwrap.sh version -a
OpenSSL 1.0.2m-dev  xx XXX xxxx
built on: reproducible build, date unspecified
platform: linux-x86_64
options:  bn(64,64) rc4(16x,int) des(idx,cisc,16,int) idea(int) blowfish(idx)
compiler: gcc -I. -I.. -I../include  -DOPENSSL_THREADS -D_REENTRANT -DDSO_DLFCN
-DHAVE_DLFCN_H -Wa,--noexecstack -m64 -DL_ENDIAN -O3 -Wall -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -
DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DRC4_ASM -DSH
A1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DAES_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DBSAES_ASM -DW
HIRLPOOL_ASM -DGHASH_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM
OPENSSLDIR: "/usr/local/ssl"
```

After your perform the `git clone`, you shoud `git checkout OpenSSL_1_0_2-stable`.

Related, I can duplicate your OpenSSL 1.1.0 results with:

```
$ git checkout OpenSSL_1_1_0-stable
Branch OpenSSL_1_1_0-stable set up to track remote branch OpenSSL_1_1_0-stable from origin.
Switched to a new branch 'OpenSSL_1_1_0-stable'

$ ./config
...
$ make -j 10
...
$ make check
...
All tests successful.
Files=95, Tests=555, 173 wallclock secs ( 1.29 usr  0.16 sys + 112.13 cusr 78.73 csys = 192.31 CPU)
Result: PASS
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/jwalton/openssl'
```

---

OpenSSL 1.1.0 explains this result:

> ```
> $ nm /usr/local/lib/libssl.* | grep SSL_l
> 00000000000143a0 T _SSL_load_client_CA_file
> 0000000000001590 T _SSL_load_client_CA_file
> 00000000000143a0 T _SSL_load_client_CA_file
> ```

You will have `OPENSSL_init_ssl`, not `SSL_library_init`. Related, see [Library Initialization](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Library_Initialization) on the OpenSSL wiki.

---

> ```
> | #ifdef __cplusplus
> | extern "C"
> | #endif
> | char SSL_library_init ();
> | int
> | main ()
> | {
> | return SSL_library_init ();
> |   ;
> |   return 0;
> | }
> ```

Regarding, *"It's just running a simple test program..."*, we need to see more. In particular, the `-I` and the `-L` you used during configuration.

I've got a feeling you need to `CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/ssl/include`, `CFLAGS=-I/usr/local/ssl/include` and `LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/ssl/lib` when you run configure.

You can see some examples of configuring Autools projects at [Noloader | Build-Scripts](https://github.com/noloader/Build-Scripts). You might be able to build ClamAV by copy/paste over the build-ssh.sh script. You need zLib and OpenSSL; just swap ClamAV and SSH.

However, I tired a quick port to build ClamAV from sources, and it failed because ClamAV cannot use libraries in `/usr/local/lib64`. I uploaded `build-clamav.sh` so you can use it as a starting point, if desired. Also see [ClamAV Issue 11929](https://bugzilla.clamav.net/show_bug.cgi?id=11929).

Comment: $ nm /usr/local/lib/libssl.* | grep OPENSSL_init_ssl
0000000000019b20 T _OPENSSL_init_ssl
00000000000603e4 b _OPENSSL_init_ssl.stoperrset
0000000000000000 T _OPENSSL_init_ssl
0000000000000540 b _OPENSSL_init_ssl.stoperrset
                 U _OPENSSL_init_ssl
                 U _OPENSSL_init_ssl
0000000000019b20 T _OPENSSL_init_ssl
00000000000603e4 b _OPENSSL_init_ssl.stoperrset
David-Laxers-MacBook-Pro:openssl davidlaxer$

Comment: The 'configure' program in 'clamav-0.99.2/' is invoking  SSL_library_init (); on line 17,958.  Seems like a version issue.  The requirements page doesn't appear to list the openssl version requirement.  https://www.clamav.net/documents/installing-clamav#requirements

Comment: @dbl001 - Right; you need to use OpenSSL 1.0.2 and below; not OpenSSL 1.1.0 or higher. Its a common problem for packages. Even OpenSSH cannot build with OpenSSL 1.1.0. But you may have more problems after you sort out the OpenSSL version issue.

Comment: I rebuilt with OpenSSL 1.0.2-stable.  $ nm /usr/local/ssl/lib/libssl.a | grep SSL_library_init
00000000 T _SSL_library_init

Comment: $  CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/ssl/include" LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/ssl/lib" CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/ssl/include" ./configure

Comment: Still getting error because it's looking in /usr/local/lib: gcc -o conftest -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/ssl/include -L/usr/local/lib -lssl -lcrypto -lz conftest.c -lssl -lcrypto -lz  >&5
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_SSL_library_init", referenced from:
      _main in conftest-871fc1.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Comment: $ env | grep FLAGS
LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/ssl/lib
CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/ssl/include
XPC_FLAGS=0x0
CFLAGS=-I/usr/local/ssl/include

Comment: *"Still getting error because it's looking in..."* - File a bug report against ClamAV. They are making assumptions that do not hold and its breaking the configuration process.

Comment: @dbl001 - It looks like you need to use `clamav-0.99.3-beta1` (or apply the patch manually). I updated the [`build-clamav.sh`](https://github.com/noloader/Build-Scripts) script to use `clamav-0.99.3-beta1`. I don't like using beta and bleeding edge software. Sorry about that.

Comment: I tried installing clamav-0.99.3-beta1, building with: CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/ssl/include" LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/ssl/lib" CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/ssl/include" ./configure  I get the same problem:
.configure:17982: gcc -o conftest -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/ssl/include -L/usr/local/lib conftest.c   -lssl -lcrypto -lz >&5
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_SSL_library_init", referenced from:
      _main in conftest-2730c9.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)